# Why is the Request-html Module not working with Apple's M1 Chip?

Tags: visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I am getting the error zsh: illegal hardware instruction if I try to use the request-html module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a virtual environment on Python. The error disappears if you install your modules including request-html into a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with an Apple M1 since last month, and I have not seen this behavior.

My setup is the following:

```
1 - I  have [Pyenv][1], a python version manager. 

2 - I always use a virtual environment, since you should avoid 
installing libraries and changing the root python in your computer. 

3 - I have requests always on the last version >. 2.28, since M1 is new hardware, and It can cause trouble in versions for other hardware.
```

I really recommend you use the same setup since it will preserve your python root and also avoid these problems.

So, try the following:
1 -  install pyenv
2 - Install python 3.10 or > versions, using pyenv.
3 - Install python venv
4 - create a virtual environment, and install requests
5 - Run your code, using the virtual environment, and check if it solves your problem.